# Travelling while having long sejour in france

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, long-stay-visas

I am married to a french and have the long sejour visa. I registered at the OFII and received a paper document as a confirmation. They said that i don't need a stamp as long as I have this paper. Is it true? and can I leave france for Lebanon and come back without facing any problems? The lady at the OFII said that my medical examination and language test won't happen before August. I hope anyone can clarify if you have been in this situation before.

Thank you,
Rola

Comment: What is the name or title on your paper document?  Will you be returning to France before your long-stay visa expires?

Answer (score 4):

With regard to returning to France:

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states:

> NOTE 30627: Receipts of application for Renewal of a
>      residence permit issued by France (Recepisse de demande de
>      carte de sejour - renouvellement de titre de sejour) are
>      accepted if accompanied by the expired residence permit or
>      an expired "D" visa.
>      - Receipts of application for a first residence permit
>      (Recepisse de demande de carte de sejour - delivrance d'un
>      premier titre de sejour) are not accepted.

Of course, if your D visa has not yet expired, you can still travel back to France with that.